# Need to add link to button in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, button

I don't know how to code. I need to add a link to this button code in a content block on Wordpress:

```
 [/vc_column_text]
[button button_text="Volunteer Now" button_type="uk-button-primary" alignment="uk-text-center" css_animation="uk-animation-fade" delay_animation="600" dahz_id="1534326893808-7e6a8e5c-ddf7"]
[/vc_column][vc_column width="1/6" dahz_id="1534326271615-35814182-a972"][/vc_column][/vc_row][/vc_section]
```

Answer (score 0):

We add links using a tag. a for anchor. This is the syntax of a tag. Here href is an attribute where we put the destination URL.

```html
<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/">Stack Overflow Questions</a>
```

For your case, you want to add a link on a button.

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" style="padding: 5px 10px; cursor:pointer; background-color: dodgerblue; text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px;">
  Stack Overflow Questions
</a>
```

In my opinion, I suggest you use this format. Here I use anchor tag but I designed it like a button. Now you add this code and change the URL and the text what you want to show on your website. you can change the background color, font size, button size by changing the padding value.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Thank you!. When I insert this code it doesn't create a button, it just puts the code on the page. Because this is a content block in Wordpress I'm assuming I have to use this code. The button is on the page, it just links to nothing and I need it to link to a google form.